# Implementing string method split() into the object literal w/ loop code

Tags: javascript, loops, split, object-literal

1st code:

```js
var str = "Hello";
var arr = str.split("");
var text = "";
var i;
for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    text += arr[i] + "<br>"
}
document.write(text);
```

2nd code:
I want to implement the string method split() in the object literal code

```js
var greeting = {
  str: "Hello",
  arr: str.split(""), // string method: split()
  text: " ",
  loop: function() {
      for (var i = 0; i < this.arr.length; i++) {
       this.text += this.arr[i] + "<br>"
       }
      document.write(this.text);
      }
    };
greeting.loop();
```

So the 2nd code would output the same as the 1st code

Comment: Why? What's wrong with the first bit of code?

Comment: I just want the multiple variable to be put into as one variable an object literal

Comment: In the second bit of code, you write :

arr: str.split("") but what is "str" in this context? undefined.

Comment: someone already answer this thx .....str is just a variable name

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be to define `arr` inside the `loop` function, like this:

```js
var greeting = {
  str: "Hello",
  text: " ",
  loop: function() {
      var arr = this.str.split("");
      for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) { 
       this.text += arr[i] + "<br>"
       }
      document.write(this.text);
      }
    };
greeting.loop();
```